# Add ScrollTo with Navigation using Isotope datafiltering

Tags: wordpress, scrollto, jquery-isotope

Currently I have a Wordpress website that uses Isotope to display all posts in a grid and there is a fixed navigation that is used for filtering the post categories.

I am trying to add some Javascript or Jquery to scroll to the top of the page when a navigation item is clicked - so it filters the category and also scrolls to the top of the page.

I have been trying different examples for a while and cannot figure it out.
I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Currently my navigation looks like this:

```
    <div class="menuContainer right">
       <ul id="options" class="option-set">
         <li><a href="#" data-filter=".1">Editorial</a></li>
         <li>&nbsp;</li>
         <li><a href="#" data-filter=".4">Covers</a></li>
         <li>&nbsp;</li>
         <li><a href="#" data-filter=".3">Advertising</a></li>
         <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".5">Film</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>`
```

and the current js.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var mycontainer = jQuery('#isocontent');
     mycontainer.isotope({
     itemSelector: '.postContainer',
     });

   // filter items when filter link is clicked
jQuery('#options a').click(function(){
  var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
  mycontainer.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;  
  });

// set selected menu items
   var $optionSets = $('.option-set'),
       $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

       $optionLinks.click(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
      }
   var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
   $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $this.addClass('selected'); 

});

});
 </script>
```

All help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Hard to understand without an online sandbox or jsfiddle - why do you need, for example, $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); when filtering with buttons on the top of your page? Or are your navigation buttons at the bottom of your page? Some visual of what you have or what you want would be very helpful...

Comment: The problem that I am having is when the viewer scrolls down the page for a while and then clicks 'Film' (for example)  in the navigation - all the content disappears besides Film - which is automatically shown at the top. Because the filtered content goes straight to the top the viewer is left looking at a blank screen as they are halfway down the page. 

I need to somehow implement a ScrollTo so when the navigation is clicked it filters the content and also scrolls back to the top of the page. 

How can I go about this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please let me know if you can see what I mean from looking at the URL + source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seeing is believing :) easier to understand what you want. Basically, all you have to do is to hook up what I commented before on your Editorial, Covers, Advertising, Film links. Since you use Isotope with filtering, you have assigned click functions to your links already...

```
// stuff

<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Show all, home, whatever</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".editorial">Editorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".covers">Covers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".advertising">Advertising</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".film">Film</a></li>
</ul>

// more stuff

$('#filters a').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
    $('body,html').animate({ // always scrolls to the top when filter link is clicked
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
});​

// even more stuff
```

Comment: Fantastic!
That is perfect.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good to hear. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct in that case.